# Pattern Matching Case Match using Scala

Tags: scala

Having issues with trying to get my case match to work as expected.
The outcome I am looking for is as follows:

case 1 OR 2 => randomly select one reference

case any other number above 2 => randomly select (number - 2) reference

case None => throw exception

Im having problems implementing this. so far I have:

```
 val randomList: List = actualList.size match {
      case 1 => scala.util.Random.shuffle(actualList).take(1)
      case x? => scala.util.Random.shuffle(actualList).take(2)
      case None => throw new IllegalStateException("references have not been generated successfully.")
    }
```

I get an error message with the 'None' stating the pattern type is incompatible with expected type Int.

If there is a better way to implement this, please do share.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what does "case None" represent in your description? `actualList.size` produces `Int` so it would never be `None`. Did you mean `0`?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco Hi yes, that's what i meant. it literally just went over my head that the list was an Int >.< Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can shuffle right away to simplify each expression in `case` clauses:

```
  val actualList = List(1, 2, 3)
  val shuffled = Random.shuffle(actualList)

  shuffled.size match {
    case 0 => throw new RuntimeException()
    case 1 | 2 => shuffled.take(1)
    case _ => shuffled.take(2)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `|`, guard and `_` to achieve this

```
  val randomList: List = actualList.size match {
      case 0 => throw new IllegalStateException("references have not been generated successfully.")
      case 1 | 2 => scala.util.Random.shuffle(actualList).take(1)
      case _ => scala.util.Random.shuffle(actualList).take(2)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, It seems so simple now that i can see it demonstrated